# Comparing the strength of metallic bonds

Tags: bond, metal, ionic-compounds, boiling-point

Why is the boiling point of iron higher than magnesium?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main reasons:

1. Metallic bonding is more prevalent for transition metal elements because there are more electrons available for delocalization (from s and d orbitals), while Magnesium has only s electrons
2. Fe has a higher atomic mass than Mg --> van der Waals forces are stronger.

Comment: Is there any impact on the atomic radius too?

Comment: It is an unrelated property, transition metals tend to have smaller atomic radii than group 1 or 2 elements because of d-metal contraction due to poor shielding of d-electrons

Comment: vdW forces aren't important here. Also related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23960/how-many-delocalised-electrons-in-gold